# Multiple Results from Array Loop in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my controller in which I am trying to add the values returned from a json request. The json returned 4 results of 13500, 13500, 25000, 13500:

$scope.conNum =0
          $scope.grandTotal=0

```
      $scope.getTotalAmounts = () ->
        for totals in data.creditInfoAccounts

          $scope.conNum  += totals.balanceAmount.asNumber()

          $scope.grandTotal = $scope.conNum

        return $scope.grandTotal



      $log.info 'totalAmounts >>>>>>> ' + $scope.getTotalAmounts() + " owed"
```

I get the value "totalAmounts >>>>>>> 65500 owed" when viewed in Chrome Dev log

I now have this in my jade file:

**span {{getTotalAmounts()}}**

But when viewed in the browser, I get a different result of '720500'

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTotalAmounts` will be evaluated many times when you reference it from a template `{{getTotalAmounts()}}`.

Any time something changes in the scope of where the template is used AngularJS can reevaluate the function.

What you should do is reset the  $scope.conNum at the start of the function.

Comment: Thanks. Works great! Reset variables now moved inside the function rather than outside: $scope.getTotalAmounts = () ->
            $scope.conNum =0
            $scope.grandTotal=0
            
            for totals in data.creditInfoAccounts
              
              $scope.conNum  += totals.balanceAmount.asNumber()
              # $scope.identity =  angular.identity
              # parseFloat($scope.conNum)
              $scope.grandTotal = $scope.conNum
              # alert $scope.grandTotal

            return $scope.grandTotal